# Desktop PSU won't turn on after being turned off or unplugged, but flicking the PSU switch fixes it

Tags: desktop

(apologies if the wrong board)

I have a new desktop computer I built, with all new parts (except for the case).

For some reason, if I unplug/replug it in, or turn the PSU switch off for more than a couple of seconds, it won't turn on via the front power switch.  The fix seems to be to then flick the PSU switch off and back on again, which usually (but not always fixes it).

So, thinking it was the front switch, I unplugged my old computer's front power switch and plugged it into the new machine - same behavior occurs.

Additionally, when it won't turn back on, when I eventually do get it to turn on, the bios screen comes up and says to enter setup to recover the BIOS settings.

Before I pull both PSUs and swap them out to see if that fixes it, I was wondering if anybody had any ideas.  It could be the case, the PSU, or some weird grounding issue. Why flicking the switch does it, I'm not sure, and it could just be timing-related at that point.

While it seems pedantic, it matters - we have enough power issues (and yes, I'm on a PSU) that this will quickly become irritating.  Part of me wants to go swap out the PSU, part of me wants to go swap out the case.  Either one is non-trivial.  So please don't just say "well don't unplug it *hyuk* *hyuk* *hyuk*)

Thanks!

UPDATE: tried two tests with another machine I had.  On both machines, I unplugged the mobo from the PSU.  I then took the cables from the old machine's PSU and plugged into the new machine's mobo.  Hit the power switch, still nothing.  (even flicking the power switch on/off didn't make any changes - tried about 20 times and it only turned on once).  So at this point I think I've eliminated both the PSU and the Switch... so, what, motherboard problem?  Or something else?

Comment: What do you mean by "we have enough power issues" exactly?

Comment: The area has frequent power outages.  But mostly I just didn't want anybody hand-waving and saying "pssssh, get a UPS and don't worry about it".

Comment: Have you mounted the motherboard to all the chassis pins - some act as a case earth. Also, are you sure your PSU is OK? Finally, when the BIOS keeps asking to go through BIOS setup, is the CMOS battery new? Have you got the CMOS reset header in the "reset" position?